# In Python, is there a good solution for asynchronously writing to a NetCDF file?

Tags: python, asynchronous, multiprocessing, netcdf

My goal is to accomplish the following:

- Do a number of calculations on multiple threads
- **Wait** until these calculations are done, then start writing the results to a NetCDF output file on one thread
- Begin the next iteration **without waiting** for the NetCDF writes to finish

Here is a simplified version of how my NetCDF output class is set up:

```
class NetcdfOutput:
    def __init__(self, filename, lon, lat):
        self.__filename = filename
        self.__lon = lon
        self.__lat = lat
        self.__nc = netCDF4.Dataset(self.__filename + ".nc", "w")
        self.__group_main = self.__nc.createGroup("Main")
        self.__group_main_var_spd = self.__group_main.createVariable("spd", "f4", ("time", "latitude", "longitude"), zlib=True,
                                                                     complevel=2, fill_value=netCDF4.default_fillvals["f4"])
        self.__group_main_var_dir = self.__group_main.createVariable("dir", "f4", ("time", "latitude", "longitude"), zlib=True,
                                                                     complevel=2, fill_value=netCDF4.default_fillvals["f4"])

    def append(self, idx, uvel, vvel):
        self.__group_main_var_spd[idx, :, :] = magnitude_from_uv(uvel, vvel)
        self.__group_main_var_dir[idx, :, :] = dir_met_to_and_from_math(direction_from_uv(uvel, vvel))
```

So, imagine we have an instance of this class called wind. To write to the NetCDF file, I just need to call wind.append. I want to do this in such a way that it doesn't block the next iteration of calculations from beginning, though.

The NetCDF writes take ~1 second and the calculations take ~2.5-3 seconds, so there is no concern of having multiple concurrent writes using the high-level method I called out above. Reducing runtime is my top priority and Python 3.7 is my target version.

I was originally planning to use multiprocessing.Pool for this, and pool.map does work fine for my computations, but when I attempt to handle the writes via pool.map_async it fails because NetcdfOutput includes a NetCDF4.Dataset object (self.__nc) and Datasets are not picklable.

As a workaround, I can see reworking the class to take a filename instead of a netCDF4.Dataset object and just opening and closing the NetCDF file with every loop iteration, but when speed is the goal opening and closing the same file hundreds of times just doesn't feel like the right answer. I admittedly haven't benchmarked this, though.

Comment: Enqueue your writes (`queue.Queue` or `multiprocessing.Queue` or `asyncio.Queue`, depending on your async model) and have a single worker thread/process/coroutine deal with the writes?

Comment: I'll look into enqueuing and report back - thanks a lot for your thoughts!

Answer (score 3):

The [threading module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) ended up being the path of least resistance. My call to write to the NetCDF file looks like this:

```
threading.Thread(target=wind.append, args=(arg1, arg2, ...)).start()
```

There was no need to change around my NetcdfOutput class or anything else in my code. I just imported the module and added this line.

It only takes ~.0008 seconds for me to run this command, which is fabulous in comparison to the original write time (~1 second). The time it takes to run this command is all that really matters too, since wind.append will always finish before the calculations for the next iteration. So, even if there are usually performance downsides to using threading (no earthly idea), they don't impact me in this case.

Comment: This line alone only creates a new threads and starts its run loop, it does not wait for the task to be done. For that, you have to call the `.join()` method of the thread. Thus your timings are irrelevant and your program may be incorrect.

Comment: As said in another comment, you should use queues and a thread/process pool to manage the concurrent execution of your program.

Comment: Right, it's my intention to run the task without specifically waiting for it to finish. The task will reliably finish before it gets called again, so while it's technically a sort of race condition, the right part of the code will always win the race.

I would happily switch to one of the various queue methods if they can take a netCDF4.Dataset as an input, but otherwise I'm not sure it's worth the effort.

Comment: And to clarify, I'm still using multiprocessing.Pool for my multi-threaded calculations because there's no pickling issue with those. Once Pool.map returns, I use threading.Thread to write to the netCDF file, and then immediately start the next round of calculations with Pool.map.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the `netCDF4.Dataset` between processes since you only need the process pool for the heavy computation, not the file writing part, thus you can avoid the pickle issue.

Here is a simple example with a heavy computation of 1 second and a file writing operation of 0.5 seconds. The heavy computations are feed to a process pool and the (serial) file writing operations are done in the main thread (though they can be offloaded to a different thread), concurrently to the heavy computations:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, Future
from time import sleep, perf_counter
import netCDF4

N = 10


def heavy_computation(i: int) -> int:
    sleep(1.0)
    return i


def long_write(value: int, variable):
    sleep(0.5)
    variable[value] = value


def main():
    with netCDF4.Dataset("test.nc", "w") as ds, ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
        main = ds.createGroup("main")
        main.createDimension("value", N)
        dir = main.createVariable("dir", "f4", ("value",))

        start = perf_counter()

        futures: list[Future[int]] = []
        for i in range(N):
            future = pool.submit(heavy_computation, i)
            futures.append(future)

        for future in futures:
            result = future.result()
            long_write(result, dir)

        elapsed = perf_counter() - start

        print(dir[:])
        print(f"Elapsed: {elapsed:.2f}s")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

For more complex setups you should use a queue to synchronise and distribute the work between processes and threads.

Comment: I appreciate the example. What is the advantage to using concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor over multiprocessing.Pool and threading.Thread, though? Like, would this be faster to run, or is this mostly just making sure the code would still succeed if long_write took longer than heavy_computation? 

Also, let's imagine that everything in main() is wrapped in a for loop. As written, wouldn't we be stuck waiting for long_write to finish before starting the next iteration of the loop? That was the main thing I was originally trying to avoid.

Comment: They essentially perform the same, choose whatever feels more natural. IMO `concurrent_futures` proposes a more modern interface based on `Future`s. Tasks can be canceled and thrown exceptions can be retrieved. Switching between a thread/process pool requires a single line change and is less weird than the `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` interface.

Comment: As written yes, the next iteration will wait for all the tasks feed to the process pool to finish. This is enforces by the process pool context manager (the `with` statement). If you want it to be asynchronous, then put your main loop inside that context manager. You can also use the `concurrent.futures.wait` function to manually wait for all futures to finish.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for explaining all of that! Much appreciated.